# Bosch Induction Hob Keeps Restarting

Tags: electrical, wiring, appliances

I just purchased and wired a bosch PXY675DW4E and it keeps restarting.

https://youtu.be/F9wrC7jOavI
https://youtu.be/7aZgkkcT6w4

Also restarting randomly from time to time.

I wired it according to the instructions on european one phase electricity 230V, I have a 4mm^2 cooper 3 core cable that comes out of the wall with a dedicated  20A fuse, from there I used the provided 5 wire cable, black and brown connected to live, gray and blue connected to neutral and green-yellow to grounding.

At the induction hob I've connected the wires like in this diagram: https://www.electriciansforums.net/proxy.php?image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ibb.co%2Fm0Dqwmf%2F1.jpg&hash=6c25e4c5344f47473fcd4f76b1a808a3 for 1N~ and tested with a multimeter between live and neutral and also live and grounding and it's fine.

Also, sometimes I can't even make it start and have to wait a couple of hours with the fuse down to get to the point in the videos. Also worth mentioning I've activated power management feature and set it at a 20A limit maybe this is what it's keeping it off.

Any ideas before I call the technicians?

Comment: I've used wago 221 for the wall connections

Comment: I would skip the power management feature and not worry about it until it trips a breaker.

Comment: Maybe I missed it , but what do you mean by restarting?  A new Hob or device , Time to return , not really that much to go wrong With wiring  if it powers up and the breaker and RCD don’t trip.